# latest django and mongo engine, do you need to edit settings.py to install it?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

In [this tutorial](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/guide/connecting.html#guide-connecting), it never says to edit the settings.py, in the previous docs, which supported django 1.5 you needed to edit settings.py.

So do you need to edit that file or not? Did the author skip that part because it was kinda obvious?

I actually don't see the name `settings.py` in the new docs, and there aren't too many mongo db django tutorials on the web. And the questions here, if  any are outdated. Thereby I'm sorry if this turns out to be a naive question.

And if you want to use pymongo, AFAIK you don't connect from settings.py so I just had to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I like to have all my database configs in settings, so I have mongo database configuration in settings.py along with my relational database configs:

```
MONGO_DBS = {
    'default': {
        'alias': 'default',         # the alias that Documents refer to
        'name': 'default',          # the name of the database to connect to
        'host': 'localhost',        # the host
        'port': 27017,              # the port
        'username': '',             # not implemented
        'password': '',             # not implemented
        'enabled': False,           # whether or not we connect to this database
    },
}
```

Then, I have a little snippet of code that runs in settings.py (cue some grumbling) and connects to all of the relevant mongo instances:

```
from mongoengine import connect
import sys

if not (len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == 'test'):
    # Don't run this if we're running in unit tests. The test runner will spin
    # up the appropriate databases and spin them down appropriately.
    for db_name in MONGO_DBS:
        db_meta = MONGO_DBS[db_name]
        if db_meta['enabled'] and 'alias' in db_meta:
            connect(db_meta['name'], alias=db_meta['alias'], host=db_meta['host'], port=db_meta['port'],
                lazy_connect=db_meta.get('lazy', True))
```

Obviously, this code is still somewhat incomplete in so far as authentication doesn't happen. But it should be a reasonable launching point for you.

I should add that I just dug up references to settings.py in the django documentation page for mongoengine. Currently, it's located at http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/django.html.

Lastly, I should add that this advice applies through mongoengine 0.8.7 (latest as of this answer). YMMV with future versions.